# localstorage only showing the last prompt input

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, alertify

Hi I am storing the input from user in localstorage using the alertify prompt in javascript but when trying to display the localstorage variable using innerhtml it is only showing the last prompt which a user is adding. adding the code and demo to explain my problem. I think the localstorage is working fine and it has something to do with the loop and the innerhtml not working outside the if condition maybe?

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("username") === null) {
  alertify.prompt( "What is your name?", function (e, str) {
    if (e) {
        var myname = str;
    localStorage.setItem('username', myname);
    document.getElementById("welcometext").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("username");
    } else {
    alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");
    }
});
}

//add the status
if (localStorage.getItem("status") === null) {
  alertify.prompt( "Are you assigned to any role as of now? (FT, PT, NA)", function (e, str3) {
    if (e) {
        var mystatus = str3;
    localStorage.setItem('status', mystatus);
    document.getElementById("registeredstatus").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("status");
    } else {
    alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");
    }
});
}
//add the email

if (localStorage.getItem("email") === null) {
  alertify.prompt( "What is your email?", function (e, str2) {
    if (e) {
        var myemail = str2;
    localStorage.setItem('email', myemail);
    document.getElementById("registeredemail").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("email");
    } else {
    alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");
    }
});
}

//add the starting date
if (localStorage.getItem("date") === null) {
  alertify.prompt( "When did you started your bootcamp training? FORMAT: (DD-MM-YEAR)", function (e, str4) {
    if (e) {
        var mydate = str4;
    localStorage.setItem('date', mydate);
    document.getElementById("registereddate").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("date");
    } else {
    alertify.error("You've clicked Cancel");
    }
});
}
//for inside html
document.getElementById("welcometext").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("username");
document.getElementById("registeredemail").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("email");
document.getElementById("registeredstatus").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("status");
document.getElementById("registereddate").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("date");
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alertify.js/0.3.10/alertify.core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alertify.js/0.3.10/alertify.default.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alertify.js/0.3.10/alertify.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Welcome to your Bootcamp Tracker: <span id="welcometext"></span></h4>
<h4>Your Registered Email with us is : <span id="registeredemail"></span></h4>
<h4>Your Bootcamp Starting Date : <span id="registereddate"></span></h4>
<h4>Your current status for work is : <span id="registeredstatus"></span></h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "do with the loop " What loop?

Comment: The issue I see is the fact you are treating something that is asynchronous as synchronous. The code for alertify.prompt runs and does not wait until it is is done to continue.

Comment: sorry I mean the if condition. @epascarello

Comment: I just want to use the prompt inputs as to save in localstorage and then use it in the innerhtml on html side of page.

Comment: I understand. I have no clue about the library you are using so I can not tell it is supports promises. The answer depends on what that library supports.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the library, the library is just a simple styled prompt which replaces the default javascript prompt. The script is able to save the inputs in localstorage but struggling to display it using innerhtml.

Comment: It 100% has to do with the library and you expecting an asynchronous call being synchronous.